# Bootstrap não faz o que eu quero

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

Bom dia gente.

Sou novo na comunidade e ai vai minha primeira pergunta.
Estou tentando centralizar meu form com bootstrap na tela mas não quer funcionar nem a pau, já tentei no form, já tentei criar nova div, já botei div dentro de div, usei todos os tipos de cols de grid que podia imaginar mas a classe .justify-content-center não está funcionando. Meu último código foi esse aqui.

Obs.: Não liguem para estilização do site, depois vou alterar a aparência.

```css
html{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}

header{
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid;
}

footer{
 padding-top: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: #12E5CF;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu{
 width: 100%;
}

#menu .btnMenu{
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: black;
 padding: 2px;
 background-color: grey;
 border: 2px;
 border-right: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 font-size: 24px;
 display: inline;
}

#menu .btnMenu:hover{
 background-color: green;
 border: 2px;
 border-right: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
    animation: btnAnimacao 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btnAnimacao{
 100%{
  background-color: red;
   margin-top: 10px;
   bottom: 0px;
   border: 2px;
   border-left: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   text-indent: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title></title>

 <!--jquery js -->
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 
 <!--3 LINKS REL DE BOOTSTRAP: COMP AND MINI CSS, OPTIONAL THEME, COMP AND MIN JAVASCRIPT-->
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <!--CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/principal.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animacao.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header class="container-fluid">
  <div id="menu" class="col-md-12" align="center;">
   <bottom>
    <div class="btnMenu">Home</div>
    <div class="btnMenu">Stream</div>
    <div class="btnMenu">Vídeos</div>
   </bottom>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-sm-center justify-content-md-center justify-content-xl-center justify-content-xs-center">
   <div class="col-5 offset-5 col-sm-5 offset-sm-5 col-md-5 offset-md-5 col-xl-5 offset-xl-5 col-xs-5 offset-xs-5">
    <form action="" method="post">
     <p>
      Título:<br>
      <input type="text" name="nTitulo" id="iTitulo" placeholder="Digite o título da notícia." size="30">
     </p>
     <p>
      Texto<br>
      <textarea cols="38" rows="5"></textarea>
     </p>
     <p>
      Dia da Postagem<br>
      <input type="date" name="nData" id="iData">
     </p>
     <p>
      Foto<br>
      <input type="file" name="nFoto" id="iFoto">
     </p>
     <center><input type="submit" name=""></center>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
  
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara vc está usando o Bootstrap 3, mas tentando alinhar com as classes do Bootstrap 4... Ai não tem como dar certo.

Documentação oficial do BS3 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting

Repare que eu não alterei nada no seu código, apenas tirei as classes do BS4 e coloquei o `offset` do BS3 e funcionou!

**OBS:** Como vc está usando `col-md` para ver o alinhamento vc precisa expandir para tela toda para ver ele alinhado (exiba em "página toda"), pois quando a tela é menor que `col-md` a coluna fica com 100% da largura ai não alinha pq vc não tratou seus campo pra ficaram 100% em telas pequenas.

**OBS2:** Nuca utilize `<input>` dentro da tag `<p>` isso é errado na estrutura do HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

 <title></title>

 <!--jquery js -->
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
 
 <!--3 LINKS REL DE BOOTSTRAP: COMP AND MINI CSS, OPTIONAL THEME, COMP AND MIN JAVASCRIPT-->
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <!--CSS-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/principal.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animacao.css">
  <style>
  html{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}

header{
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: green;
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 border-bottom: 4px solid;
}

footer{
 padding-top: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 background-color: #12E5CF;
 text-align: center;
}

#menu{
 width: 100%;
}

#menu .btnMenu{
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: black;
 padding: 2px;
 background-color: grey;
 border: 2px;
 border-right: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
 font-size: 24px;
 display: inline;
}

#menu .btnMenu:hover{
 background-color: green;
 border: 2px;
 border-right: 5px;
 border-style: solid;
    animation: btnAnimacao 0.1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes btnAnimacao{
 100%{
  background-color: red;
   margin-top: 10px;
   bottom: 0px;
   border: 2px;
   border-left: 5px;
   border-style: solid;
   text-indent: 5px;
  }
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <header class="container-fluid">
  <div id="menu" class="col-md-12" align="center;">
   <bottom>
    <div class="btnMenu">Home</div>
    <div class="btnMenu">Stream</div>
    <div class="btnMenu">Vídeos</div>
   </bottom>
  </div>
  </header>
 <main class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row ">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 ">
    <form action="" method="post">
     <p>
      Título: Esse IMPUT tem 100% de largura
      
     </p>
<input style="width:100%" type="text" name="nTitulo" id="iTitulo" placeholder="Digite o título da notícia." size="30">
     <p>
      Texto<br>
      <textarea cols="38" rows="5"></textarea>
     </p>
     <p>
      Dia da Postagem<br>
      <input type="date" name="nData" id="iData">
     </p>
     <p>
      Foto<br>
      <input type="file" name="nFoto" id="iFoto">
     </p>
     <center><input type="submit" name=""></center>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
  
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**DICA:** Sempre que pesquisar documentação de Bootstrap no Goolge verifique se é a documentação da versão que vc precisa!

Comment: Pow, que vergonha xD. Ainda tenho muito a aprender, ainda bem que agora tenho a comunidade para dar uma força. Obrigado hugocsl. Só não entendi muito bem esse ponto do 100% em telas pequenas, realmente está ficando alinhado a esquerda.Como faço para arrumar?

Comment: @Unova a primeira coisa a fazer é retirar os inputs de dentro das tag P. Depois disso vc pode colocar um classe de `width:100%` nesses inputs quando a tela for menor que 765px de largura. Dessa forma o input ocupa 100% da largura da tela e vai ficar "alinhado". Repare que eu editei minha resposta e já fiz esse ajuste no primeiro `input` do form pra vc ver e entender melhor. Me fala se vc entendeu direitinho blz

Comment: @Unova só mais uma coisa. Se alguma resposta resolveu o seu  problema considere marcar alguma delas como Resposta Aceita ✔ , assim a pergunta não fica pendente no site como Pergunta sem Reposta Aceita, sendo que já foi resolvida. Boa sorte com o projeto.

Comment: sou novo aqui, não sei marcar as respostas. xD

Comment: Consegui, ficou muito bom, vou adicionar um padding so pra ficar mais organizadinho. Obrigado, já marquei sua resposta.

Comment: @Unova valeu jovem. Lembre-se sempre de verificar a versão ok rss. Tmj

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você deve apagar as classes da `div` pai do form e inserir a seguinte classe: `text-center`.

Uma maneira de fazer isso sem depender das classes do Bootstrap seria aplicar esse estilo na `div` pai do `form`:

```
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado Felipe Augusto.

Comment: @Unova não foi nada, não de marcar como certa! :D

Answer (score 0):

Deixa o seu form só com uma div pai, e usa o display flex nela. Por Exemplo:

```
<style>

.divpai{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
</style>

<div class="divpai">

   <form></form>

</div>
```

Basicamente o **justify-content: center;** vai alinhar o form na horizontal e o **align-items: center;** alinha o form na vertical.